# Unable to start android emulator

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I am facing an issue with Android emulator. I am unable to start it and getting the below log instead. I have also searched online for solution but none worked for me. My graphics drivers are updated and there is no issue with the system. The option to change "Emulated performance" is also disabled to edit. 
Please help and thanks in advance.

```
10:33   * daemon started successfully

10:33   Emulator: init: Could not find wglGetExtensionsString!

10:33   Emulator: getGLES2ExtensionString: Could not find GLES 2.x config!

10:33   Emulator: Failed to obtain GLES 2.x extensions string!

10:33   Emulator: Could not initialize emulated framebuffer

10:33   Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `goldfish_audio_in'

10:33   Emulator: qemu-system-i386.exe: warning: opening audio input failed

10:33   Emulator: audio: Failed to create voice `adc'

10:33   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, use '-gpu off' to disable it.

10:34   Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

Comment: What kind of GPU you are using? Do you have drivers installed? Have you tried to run `./emulator -gpu off` to check on that error message?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried now and it has started but very slow and lagging.

Comment: So, what helped? Emulator flag? Lags might be a part of CPU and / or GPU emulation.

Comment: This command helped me: emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_27 -gpu off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use x86 based Android Virtual Device(AVD) it is 10x faster than normal one